# Save tree form recursively and emit event on finish

Tags: angular, typescript, recursion, tree, rxjs

I have a form with nested forms like that

```
Form 1
-- Form 1.1
-- Form 1.2
```

What I need is save Form 1, then save Form 1.1 and Form 1.2 using `Id` retrieved from saving `Form 1` and after that emit that all children are saved.

I have to do this dynamically since the depth of this form is much bigger.

*How is it better to perform this action?*

I've tried to place a directive on children component's tags however I'm unable to read these components. These components are different and may be dynamic, so I cannot use `@ViewChild` on components.

I want to observe these child components for the sake of knowing how many events should be emmitted before telling parent component that everything is ready.

For now I can only think of a some service that would contain counts for every parent.

### Update #1

Here is a [StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-vutrj7?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts) and is a simplified version of what I have. In real app there is a dynamic component presence as well as dynamic parameter names (the ones I have to pass from parent to connect children) and nesting level of the form.

I've tried to cover workflow details with comments.

**TL;DR** I need to save all Persons, then save each Person's names using personId as an additional parameter to connect them in DB, after all form part are saved I need to report parent form that everything is ready.

Comment: no need here for Rxjs. Angular has its own way, by using `ControlValueAccessors` google it, maybe you will even find examples with dynamic components

Comment: How would ControlValueAccessor make a request to an API and make its children to make the same thing with their corresponding APIs?

Comment: Its not `ControlValueAccessor`, but your Component, which implements `ControlValueAccessor`.

Comment: This accessor allows only custom form value change handling using custom inputs etc. but not saving form by its parts...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I solved my problem using next code. Hope this will help someone

```
// You should provide either "data" or "formGroup"
export interface RecForm {
    /** Data to be saved */
    data?: any;
    /** Request URI */
    request: string;
    /** Params that should be used from accumulator */
    useParams?: string[] | {
        /** Parameter to be taken from accumulator */
        use: string;
        /** Parameter alias to use */
        as: string;
    }[];
    /** Children forms to be saved */
    children?: RecForm[];
    /** FormGroup to take values from */
    formGroup?: FormGroup;
    /** Children forms grouped by name to be saved */
    childrenGroups?: {
        [index: string]: RecForm[];
    };
    /** Names to use for storing in accumulator. The array us being used for the
      * sake of agility */
    valAlias: string[];
}
```

And this is the method I use to handle that object

```
public saveRecursively(obj: RecForm, accumulator?: any): Observable<any> {
    // Variable to store form data
    let req;

    if (obj.data) {
        req = {...obj.data};
    } else {
        req = {...obj.formGroup.value};
    }

    // If there are an accumulator and parameters to be used
    // we add these parameters to the form data
    if (obj.useParams && accumulator) {
        (<any>obj.useParams).forEach(paramName => {
            if (typeof paramName === 'string') {
                req[paramName] = accumulator[paramName];
            } else {
                req[paramName.as] = accumulator[paramName.use];
            }
        });
    }


    return iif(
        () =>
            // We need to save only changed form
            obj.formGroup.touched && obj.formGroup.dirty
            // or the one that has children and does not
            // have an Id to pass it to the children
            || (
                obj.children && obj.children.length > 0
                || obj.childrenGroups && Object.keys(obj.childrenGroups).length > 0
            ) && !req.id
        ,
        defer(() => this.ss.send(obj.request, {
            data: req
        })),
        of(req.id || null)
    ).pipe(
        pluck('data'),
        map((id: string) => {
            const acc = {...accumulator};

            // Export returned ID with provided aliases adding them
            // to the accumulator
            obj.valAlias.forEach(alias => {
                acc[alias] = id;
            });

            return acc;
        }),
        switchMap((acc): any => {
            if (obj.children && obj.children.length > 0) {
                return forkJoin(
                    obj.children.map(child => this.saveRecursively(child, acc))
                );
            }
            // Save children forms if there any
            else if (obj.childrenGroups && Object.keys(obj.childrenGroups).length > 0) {
                return forkJoin(
                    flatten(Object.values(obj.childrenGroups)).map(item => this.saveRecursively(item, acc))
                );
            }
            // If there is no children forms just return an accumulator
            else {
                return of(acc);
            }
        })
    );
}
```

Note: `flatten` is from Lodash and used to change and object of grouped forms by name into single array.

`this.ss.save` is a service's method which accepts a request and body to work out and returns an observable.

Then, I just make a service which instance is being created at the root form component.
This service contains an `object: RecForm` and couple of Lodash methods for dynamic creating and deleting nested object props.

Having this service I'm passing through the components tree `path` where I extend its value moving down the tree and use this path to add new `FormGroup`s to my object.

When I'm done I just call `saveRecursively` on the object and have everything saved as it should be.

Also if you are going to use my method and extend the object in `OnInit` don't forget to delete its value in `OnDestroy` so that any `FormArray` split into components by each control won't have any removed value.

Comment: At the end of the day, you are still iterating over the form/form values as stated in my provided answer... it doesn't matter if you pass the form as an argument to a method, you are only obfuscating the solution to make it appear more complex than it needs to be. Either way, glad you were able to solve your problem.

Comment: I'm iterating over values that I'm not aware of before. The requests and values etc. are provided by components which contain dedicated parts of form and use parent's value to be saved. Thus, I'm building fully dynamic saving workflow. I hope I didn't obfuscate anything because it's just a waste of time.

Comment: Doesn't matter if you iterate over unknown values in a wrapping method, or in the original submit method within your `app.component.ts` stackblitz example. The values are still un-known both before passing the form obj to a method, and after. You just moved the solution out of `app.component.ts` into a service method and obfuscated it to make it look different.

Comment: can you share StackBlitz Url ??

Comment: Maybe I'll try to do this later. The app is too huge to show the case. Even to show a simple mock it would take a while

Answer (score 1):

You have everything you would need at the `app.component.ts` level, to iterate through the `tree` recursively and complete your save logic without any state at the child level.

> Use your `Observable` logic in the `submit()` method to retrieve the `ID`
>   from the first save, once you receive that ID proceed to iterate over the next
>   level down values in the form and complete the next save. Once all of
>   your conditions are met at the `app.component.ts` level close the
>   form.

```
submit() {
    // Here goes an initial form submit which returns an ID of saved form
    console.log('submit a form');
    let persons: Person[] = this.formGroup.value.persons;
    for (let person of persons) {
      console.log('Saving person with Birthdate: ' + person.birthDate)
      for (let name of person.names) {
        console.log('Saving nameObject: ' + JSON.stringify(name))
      }
    }
}
```

Comment: This tree is just for simplicity. The real one is fully dynamic and not as easy describable as you've shown.

Comment: My illustration was based on the example stackblitz you provided... if the dynamic form is built in the fashion you have provided in your stackblitz, you still have all values at the `app.component.ts` level when the user initiates `submit` regardless of dynamic complexities.

Comment: However for each part of the form should be performed save call to an API. For each part on different APIs with different props.

Comment: In order to effectively interact with the API, you will need to have intimate knowledge of that data structure with props... all of which will be in the parent form when the user initiates the submit. If you would like to revise your example to be more reflective of your actual structure, I would be more than happy to review further. Without additional detail, I will not be able to help you; debating semantics is not productive towards helping solve your problem.

Answer (score 0):

Use event emitters to submit form data from your child forms to your parent form.  The parent form will then be able to collect the emitted data and you can process it however you'd like, including passing it to an Observable as you mentioned.

Comment: How do I know when I can start doing it? This emitting doesn't solve the problem of not knowing the amount of children that have to emit this event.

Comment: the children emitting events - are these calls to APIs?

Comment: Is your intention to have the child forms be separate forms from the parent form?  Or is your intention to have them be one form spread across several child components?

Comment: My intention is to save these forms spread across the tree separately. However, for saving the descendants I need to save an ancestor and pass its ID down the tree. Then save children and so on. After that I need to know that **all** children have been saved and to close the form page.

Comment: @katwhocodes children should emit events after call to API. And I need to count these children and their events so that I can know that form is fully saved and I'm free to close the form.

Comment: @Sergey here is what I can suggest: in the parent form make variable w/ id & pass to the child component: ```private parentFormId: any = parentForm.id; <child-form-component #childFormEmit [id]="id"></child-form-component>``` where it is received by the child component and passed to the grandchild component with an event emitter passing a submitted flag back up the tree:  ```@Input('id') id:any;
@Output() childFormEmit: EventEmitter<any> = new EventEmitter<any>();
<dynamic-grandchild-form-component #grandChildFormEmit [id]="id"></dynamic-grandchild-form-component>``` and so on down the tree.

Comment: @BillGardner this doesn't give me any info about submit status of all the children though.

Comment: @Sergey This is what you will submit your event emitter $event. Make a variable on the child component that is set to true when the form is submitted and then passed to an event emitter: ```childFormEmit.emit(id)``` This is then received by the parent Form ```(childFormEmit)="receiveChildFormId($event)"``` and then passed to the parent form function ```receiveChildFormId()``` where you can do what you need to do with the data.

Comment: @BillGardner but the number of children is unlimited and therefore I cannot know how many of them I should be waiting for

Comment: @Sergey You need to post code.  I've tried to help, but am guessing at this point with no code to look at.

Comment: I've tried to show what I have. Please, check the updated question